# Why does Recycler view gives null pointer exception?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` in a fragment, it is generate a  `NullPointerException` and I cannot understand the reason.

Here is my fragment activity:

```
public class Recharges extends Fragment {

public RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<GetRecharge> rechargeList = new ArrayList<>();
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
ImageView image1, image2;

@Nullable @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recharges, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new Adapterrecharge(rechargeList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    prepareRechargeData();

    return rootView;

}

private void prepareRechargeData() {
    GetRecharge recharge = new GetRecharge("Mad Max: Fury Road" );
    rechargeList.add(recharge);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Here the adapter class:

```
public class Adapterrecharge extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapterrecharge.MyViewHolder> {

private List<GetRecharge> rechargeList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    ImageView image;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}

public Adapterrecharge(List<GetRecharge> rechargeList) {
    this.rechargeList = rechargeList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.rechargelist, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    GetRecharge recharge = rechargeList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(recharge.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rechargeList.size();
}
}
```

I seem to be inflating the correct layout but still getting the error.
here is the logcat error

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.aadesh.walletuncle.Adapterrecharge.onBindViewHolder(Adapterrecharge.java:53)
   at com.example.aadesh.walletuncle.Adapterrecharge.onBindViewHolder(Adapterrecharge.java:21)
```

here is the recyclerview item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"/>
```

here is the main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:text="Recharge"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_weight="1" />



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview1">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: post your logcat where error occurs

Comment: I think there is no problem in your code . But i doubt in recyclerview item layout so can u please post your recyclerview item layout

Comment: i have posted the xml as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are couple of problems

1. you are populating prepareRechargeData() list data after you have set your adapter - so your list rechargelist doesn't have any data
2. in your `onCreateViewHolder()` your are using wrong layout `R.layout.rechargelist`
3. in your view Holder you are giving wrong id for textview `R.id.title`

try this:

```
  @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recharges, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    /*recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter((RecyclerView.Adapter) adapter);*/

    prepareRechargeData();
    adapter = new Adapterrecharge(rechargeList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return rootView;

}
```

Change your adapter to:

```
    public class Adapterrecharge extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapterrecharge.MyViewHolder> {

private List<GetRecharge> rechargeList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    ImageView image;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}

public Adapterrecharge(List<GetRecharge> rechargeList) {
    this.rechargeList = rechargeList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_layout, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    GetRecharge recharge = rechargeList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(recharge.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rechargeList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: now i am getting null pointer exception in this line 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();'

Comment: remove adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in prepareRechargeData() method..

Comment: Adapter class which method?

Comment: the class declaration and onbindviewholder method

Comment: your layout id and text view id in adapter class are not matched...with your XML layout

Answer (score 0):

You are miss matching id of Textview.
Instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/title"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you are using wrong id of Textview in MyViewHolder class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to mismatch ids. ID of TextView in xml ("text") and the one inflated in ViewHolder class ("title") are different.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/text"/>
```

Adapter class

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
}
```